# Lipschitz continuity and support of distance function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

I do not see how the following assertion holds

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed subset. define $\psi(x):=\operatorname{dist}(x,A)=\inf_{y \in A}d(x,y)$. Then $\psi$ is Lipschitz with $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{supp}(\psi)) = A^c$.

Why is $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{supp}(\psi)) = A^c$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, $\inf_a d(y,a) \leq \inf_a (d(y,z) + d(z,a)) = d(y,z) + \inf_a d(z,a)$
$$\implies \inf_a d(y,a) - \inf_a d(z,a) \leq d(y,z)$$

In the same way:

$$   \inf_a d(z,a) - \inf_a d(y,a)\leq d(y,z)$$

Conclude that $|d(A,y) - d(A,z)| \leq d(y,z)$

Hence, the function is $1-$Lipschitz. Can you handle the other assertion? (I don't have time right now, but if you don't find it I will post a hint)

Comment: I know you might still be editing but I think in the second line there are two times where you accidentally replaced "a" with "z" when you meant to replace "y" with "z".

Comment: My problem was not with showing Lipschitz continuity, but rather the second assertion, as I have written in the question. Do you know a proof of that?

Comment: What is $\{x:\psi (x)=0\}$? Can you show that this set is exactly $A$? Then apply the definition of support.

Comment: Ok I do not think this holds. Since $$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \psi(x) = 0\}$$, we then get $$A^c = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \psi(x) \neq 0\}$$, and then $$\overline{A^c} = \overline{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \psi(x) \neq 0\}} = supp(\psi)$$ and then $$supp(\psi)^° = (\overline{A^c})^° = ((A^°)^c)^° = (\overline{A^°})^c . $$ And if now we choose $A = \{0\}$, then $supp(\psi)^° =  (\overline{A^°})^c = \mathbb{R} \neq \{0\}^c = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} = A^c$.

Comment: What are these integrals supposed to be? Also, the latex code is "\operatorname{int}"

Comment: Sorry it is hard to write tex in the comments haha.